# Nginx's speed, and how to replicate it

Tags: nginx, erlang

I'm interested in this from more than an academic standpoint rather than a practical standpoint; I don't plan on creating a production webserver to compete with nginx. What I'm wondering is how exactly nginx is so fast. The top google response for this is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/86674/why-is-nginx-so-fast) thread, but it merely links to a cryptic slideshow and a general covering of different io strategies. All other results seem to simply describe how fast nginx is, rather then the reason.

I tried building a simple erlang server to try to compete with nginx, but to no avail; nginx won out. All my server does is spawn a new process for each request, uses that process to read the file to a socket, then closes the file and kills the thread. It's not complicated, but given erlang's lightweight processes and underlying aio structure I thought it would compete, but nginx still wins out by a consistent 300 ms average under a heavy stress test.

What is nginx doing that my simple server isn't? My first thought would be keeping files in main memory instead of tossing them between requests, but the filesystem cache does this already so I didn't think it would make that great of difference. Am I wrong? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: People in comments:  erlang processes aren't unix processes or threads.  Better to assume they don't have the same behavior.

Comment: That's something I was wondering too. A large part of erlang's design philosophy is to spawn new threads often, which makes me wonder if many of the design considerations taken into account when structuring a normal unix server aren't relevant when accomplishing the same goal in erlang.

Comment: erlang processes do **not** map 1.1 to OS processes or OS threads, it is **not** an erlang philosophy to spawn new **threads**, there is usually only one thread per core in an erlang VM.

Comment: s/threads/erlang processes/g in my last comment (hopefully that's the right terminology)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out my little test server was quite competitive with nginx once I told it to read files in binary mode instead of list mode.

I think a lot of the discussion in the rest of this thread may be confusing for someone unfamiliar with erlang and erlang server design. I didn't want to delete the thread since there is good information about nginx in it (and I can't, it has answers already), but I encourage anyone looking into making an erlang based server to do some research and write lots of tests, and not go only what you've read here.

Comment: The majority of the answers and comments on here from people who do not have experience of erlang can be safely disregarded. It is trivial to write a network socket server in erlang that is event driven, does not block, and is good practice to create an erlang process to handle that connection. The next issue is how many concurrent connections do you need to handle? 1 million is possible (although you need multiple IP address to handle all these sockets)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to keep this a bit simple as I'm not really an expert on this subject. But the two most important things that make Nginx fast is that it uses event polling and it **does not block.**

Event polling essentially means that one process can handle many connections, this is critical as spawning processes is very expensive time wise. Event polling should not be confused with threaded programming, though. If you want to know more about this then smarter people than I have written about it.

The second most important thing is that you do not block the Nginx process. If you do a blocking operation then all other connections will be queued waiting for you to finish. If every connection blocks then performance will quickly drop to nothing.

Nginx does far more than this to be fast, for instance minimizing context switches. These, however, are too far out of my expertise for me to be comfortable commenting on.

Comment: The cost of spawning processes is irrelevant as long as you reuse them. The reason having one process handle many connections is important is because it minimizes context switches, not because processes are expensive to create.

Comment: Indeed. But he stated in his OP that "All my server does is spawn a new process for each request", in which case he *is* spending a ton of time spawning processes.

Comment: Yes, *he* is. Nevertheless, the first sentence of second paragraph is false. If, for example, you use one process per connection, only support up to 1,000 connections, but create 1,000 processes on startup and re-use them, the cost of spawning processes will have no effect on your performance. The reason one process handling many connections is important is because it minimizes context switches, not because of the cost of process startup.

Comment: erlang processes are cheap to create and dispose of, they do **not** map 1.1 to OS processes or OS threads

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is written in C, hence it is compiled to a native machine language. Erlang has its own VM. That alone implies that you will never match the performance of a well designed C program using an Erlang program given the bytecode interpreter that the Erlang module has to go through.

Despite the fact that Erlang is based on lightweight processes and is designed to scale on a distributed architecture, it will never be able to match the performance of near real time processing systems written in native language or, in this case, Nginx.

Comment: Erlang also can run in exokernels using the exokernel VM like the programs use OS and without the OS layer, and even when Erlang can't run like native machine code, if is more important a large numer of concurrent conections, for example for WebSocket, maybe is better than Nginx because allow a soft-real-time times with a number of connections more large than Nginx.

Answer (score -3):

Well, your architecture is hopelessly inefficient. Consider, for example, if you need to do a little bit of work on each of 50 connections. How many context switches will you need? Suppose 50 connections that you are handling are ready for I/O. How many calls into the system will it take you just to discover this?

Comment: I see, so instead I should have each thread handle many connections at once.

Comment: Each thread (that handles performance-critical stuff) should basically follow this logic: If there is any work to do, do it. Otherwise, wait until there's work to do.

Comment: erlang processes are cheap to create and dispose of, they do **not** map 1.1 to OS processes or OS threads the context switching you talk about should never happen at the OS level

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It doesn't matter at what level it occurs. A context switch is a context switch regardless of level. In fact, OS level context switches are often cheaper than higher-level context switches.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there is no context switching in erlangs processes, they all run on a fixed set of threads, they have their own stack and heap, your ideas about OS level processes and threads doesn't have anything to do with erlang processes.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If they each have their own stack and heap, to go from one to another, you have to switch stacks and heaps. That's the *definition* of a context switch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are missing the point, there is'nt any higher level context switching because there is'nt any context switching, not because higher level context switching is'nt doing context switching.

Comment: @taur If each connection has its own stack and heap, how can you go from processing one connection to processing another connection without changing stacks and heaps?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can think of multiple ways of solving that using simple buffering or queueing, no magic involved.

Comment: @taur It seems completely axiomatic to me. If each connection has its own stack and heap, you can't go from processing one connection to processing another without switching stacks and heaps. Isn't that a self-evidently true tautology?

Comment: @DavidSwartz what JarrodRoberson tried to say is that OS connections don't have stacks and heaps they have interrupts instead which "switches context" to higher levels via buffers and queues and not via "context switching" which as you say would involve costly stack/heap stuff.